# pandas.Series.unique() of a feature has 0 while pandas.Series of the same feature has no 0

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a feature `LotFrontage` in `dataset`.

```
print(0 in dataset['LotFrontage']) #Prints True
print(0 in dataset['LotFrontage'].unique()) #Prints False
```

I think 0 should be present in the unique values of `LotFrontage` only if its present in `LotFrontage`. Note that the feature has no 0 values.